# I'm trying to delete a score from my database table, but database isn't updating

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I'm writing a java spring boot backend with a method submitAnswers which takes in a JSON array of key-value pairs representing question and answer keys to a personality quiz, and assigns a full personality score to the current user logged into the backend. I wrote my method so that if the current user has a score associated to its id, then I remove the existing score object (with the current user id) in the table. But for some reason, if the current logged in user has a score object associated with it, my code doesn't delete the score entry. When I submit a question-answers JSON array to submit-answers endpoint, in my IntelliJ IDE I get the error: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '153' for key 'score.user_entity_id', where 153 is the id of the current user.

This is my code for my submitAnswers method

```
package com.wang.app.rest.Controller;


import com.wang.app.rest.Models.*;
import com.wang.app.rest.Repo.ScoreRepository;
import com.wang.app.rest.Repo.UserRepository;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.wang.app.rest.service.ScoreCalculationService;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class QuizController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ScoreRepository scoreRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ScoreCalculationService scoreCalculationService; //inject the service into the controller

    private Map<Integer, AnswerInfo> questionToMap = new HashMap<>();
    //we use map interface type to make code more flexible...general map type
    //if we wanna change to a different type of map, we can do that easily
    //just change the right side of the assignment operator to a different type of map

    //(1) Extraversion, (2) Agreeableness, (3) Conscientiousness, (4) Emotional Stability, or (5) Intellect/Imagination)
    // and its direction of scoring (+ or -). These numbers should not be included in the actual survey questionnaire. For further information on scoring IPIP scales, click the following link:

    //keys in the hash map are the question numbers, values are the answer info objects
    @PostConstruct
    //this postConstruct ensures questionToMap is initialized as soon as controller is created, before requests made
    public void initQuestionToMap() {
        questionToMap.put(1, new AnswerInfo(1, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(2, new AnswerInfo(2, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(3, new AnswerInfo(3, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(4, new AnswerInfo(4, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(5, new AnswerInfo(5, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(6, new AnswerInfo(1, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(7, new AnswerInfo(2, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(8, new AnswerInfo(3, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(9, new AnswerInfo(4, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(10, new AnswerInfo(5, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(11, new AnswerInfo(1, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(12, new AnswerInfo(2, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(13, new AnswerInfo(3, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(14, new AnswerInfo(4, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(15, new AnswerInfo(5, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(16, new AnswerInfo(1, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(17, new AnswerInfo(2, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(18, new AnswerInfo(3, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(19, new AnswerInfo(4, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(20, new AnswerInfo(5, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(21, new AnswerInfo(1, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(22, new AnswerInfo(2, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(23, new AnswerInfo(3, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(24, new AnswerInfo(4, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(25, new AnswerInfo(5, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(26, new AnswerInfo(1, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(27, new AnswerInfo(2, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(28, new AnswerInfo(3, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(29, new AnswerInfo(4, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(30, new AnswerInfo(5, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(31, new AnswerInfo(1, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(32, new AnswerInfo(2, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(33, new AnswerInfo(3, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(34, new AnswerInfo(4, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(35, new AnswerInfo(5, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(36, new AnswerInfo(1, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(37, new AnswerInfo(2, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(38, new AnswerInfo(3, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(39, new AnswerInfo(4, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(40, new AnswerInfo(5, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(41, new AnswerInfo(1, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(42, new AnswerInfo(2, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(43, new AnswerInfo(3, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(44, new AnswerInfo(4, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(45, new AnswerInfo(5, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(46, new AnswerInfo(1, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(47, new AnswerInfo(2, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(48, new AnswerInfo(3, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(49, new AnswerInfo(4, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(50, new AnswerInfo(5, "-"));
    }
    //WHY IS THE return type map and not Hashmap



    @PostMapping("/submit-answers")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Score> submitAnswers(@RequestBody Map<Integer, Integer> answersData, @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails customUserDetails) {
        UserEntity currentUserEntity = customUserDetails.getUserEntity();

        // If currentUserEntity is a new entity (not yet saved), save it first so it has an ID
        if (currentUserEntity.getId() == null) {
            userRepository.save(currentUserEntity);
        } else if (currentUserEntity.getScore() != null) {
//            Score oldScore = currentUserEntity.getScore();// Unlink from the score
//            currentUserEntity.setScore(null); // Save the user entity without the score///should delete it all
//            scoreRepository.delete(oldScore); // Delete old score from database
            Score scoreRemove = scoreRepository.findById(currentUserEntity.getScore().getId()).get();
            scoreRepository.delete(scoreRemove);
        }


        // Creating answer objects and associating them with the user
        List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : answersData.entrySet()) {
            Integer questionId = entry.getKey();
            Integer answerValue = entry.getValue();

            Answer answer = new Answer(questionId, answerValue);
            answer.setUserEntity(currentUserEntity); // Associate the answer with the user
            answers.add(answer);  // Add the answer to the answers list
        }

        // Set answers for the user
        currentUserEntity.setAnswers(answers);

        // Calculating score based on answers
        Score score = (scoreCalculationService.calculateScore(answers, questionToMap));//buggy still if i do score.setUsereNTTIY...
//        score.setUserEntity(currentUserEntity);//the culprit here...
        score.setUserEntity(currentUserEntity); // Set the relationship in the Score entity first
        currentUserEntity.setScore(score);
        currentUserEntity.setUsername(customUserDetails.getUsername());
        // Associate the score with the user on both sides of the relationship
//if setting relationship in userentity first, then set into score....relationship might point to entity that hasnt been persistee dyet

        // Save the user entity which should cascade the saves to Score and Answer
        userRepository.save(currentUserEntity);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(score);
   }
}
```

Here are my Score and UserEntity models:

```
package com.wang.app.rest.Models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity

public class Score {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_entity_id")
    private UserEntity user;
    //this is a foreign key
    //should store the same value of userentity's id.

    @Column
    private int Extraversion;

    @Column
    private int Agreeableness;

    private int Conscientiousness;

    private int EmotionalStability;

    private int Intellect;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getExtraversion() {
        return Extraversion;
    }

    public void setExtraversion(int extraversion) {
        Extraversion = extraversion;
    }

    public int getAgreeableness() {
        return Agreeableness;
    }

    public void setAgreeableness(int agreeableness) {
        Agreeableness = agreeableness;
    }

    public int getConscientiousness() {
        return Conscientiousness;
    }

    public void setConscientiousness(int conscientiousness) {
        Conscientiousness = conscientiousness;
    }

    public int getEmotionalStability() {
        return EmotionalStability;
    }

    public void setEmotionalStability(int emotionalStability) {
        EmotionalStability = emotionalStability;
    }
    public int getIntellect() {
        return Intellect;
    }

    public void setIntellect(int intellect) {
        Intellect = intellect;
    }


    public UserEntity getUserEntity() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Score{" +
                "extraversion=" + getExtraversion() +
                ", agreeableness=" + getAgreeableness() +
                ", conscientiousness=" + getConscientiousness() +
                ", emotionalStability=" + getEmotionalStability()+
                ", intellect=" +getIntellect() +
                '}';
    }
    public void setUserEntity(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

```
package com.wang.app.rest.Models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jdk.jfr.DataAmount;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    private String username;

    private String password = "defaultPassword";


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) //want roles to be shown
    //fetchtype eager: when we get user, we want to get roles as well
    //cascade type all: if we delete user, we want to delete roles as well
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Answer> answers;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    //added cascadetype.all based on baeldung
    private Score score;

    public void setScore(Score score){
        this.score = score;
    }



}
```

I followed this tutorial:

```
//https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-data-jpa-delete-records-from-mysql/
```

to delete the score record from my score table..

Comment: your UserEntity's ID doesn't make sense: how can you have the id column set by the User's id and also mark it as set via IDENTITY? You might be missing other warnings and exceptions indicating problems in the model which might cause it to behave counter to what you expect. You are also using @Data with lazy relationships - might want to look at how Lombok behaves as what it generates might be counter to what you want. Lastly, the first part of your code seems strange - you call scoreRepository.delete(scoreRemove), but don't remove the score from the currentUserEntity which is used in answers

Comment: I would guess that you also have cascade.ALL on your Answer.user relation, which causes save(answer) to cascade over the currentUserEntity and also cascade over the score that you are looking to remove. Fully clean up the currentUserEntity by calling currentUserEntity.setScore(null); before calling scoreRepository.delete(scoreRemove); and it should then work.

Answer (score 0):

You added the **mappedBy** attribute to UserEntity which means that now it's in charge of managing the relationship.

You can delete a score by setting UserEntity's score to null.

```
currentUserEntity.setScore(null);
```